# Best practice to use aria-label as a selector for styling

Tags: css, css-selectors, accessibility, wai-aria

I am styling a table that has table cells with (non-interactive) checkmarks in it. The checkmark icons are added via CSS. As there is no accessible content in it, I added an `aria-label` to it. Now I wonder if it is a good idea to use this attribute as a CSS selector to add those checkmark icons like this:

```
td[aria-label="yes"] {
  &:after {
    content: '\f00c';
    font-family: $font-family-icons;
  }
}
```

I learned that using ARIA attributes as selectors is generally a good practice, at least for state related attributes like `aria-hidden`, `aria-expanded` etc. In this case it made sense to me to have the td styling coupled to the corresponding label. But of course if those labels change at some time I'll need to adapt the CSS too.

Do you know any other drawbacks apart from that? Or do you have ideas on how to solve this more elegantly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To represent control states that are not natively conveyed in HTML, such as expanded (for example), then leaning on ARIA attributes as style selectors can be a good fit.

In this case you are relying on CSS to add content to a page based on ARIA I do not think you need. First, support for `aria-label` (on `<td>`s as well as other elements) [can be shaky on older browser / screen reader combos](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/), and second, [support for CSS generated content by older browser / screen reader combos](http://tink.uk/accessibility-support-for-css-generated-content/) can be more shaky. I know nothing about your users, however, to know if this matters.

This also assumes the CSS loads without any issue (network drops, etc).

This means some users may never hear nor see the value in the cell.

I try to ensure that the raw content is available regardless of whether the CSS loads to style it, and I also try to limit my reliance on ARIA.

That being said, `aria-hidden` support is generally historically better than the two issues I raise above.

Let me toss another idea your way. This is not necessarily better, but I think it is more robust when considering unknown user AT configurations and potential network issues.

I put both the text and checkmark into the `<td>`. If the CSS never loads (or the users is on a really old browser), no big deal. The worst that will happen is a user sees / hears "Yes check."

Then the `aria-hidden` makes sure the checkmark does not get announced to screen readers. The CSS hides the text from sighted users. And I think you have the effect you want.

```
<td>
 <span class="visually-hidden">Yes</span>
 <span aria-hidden="true">&#10004;</span>
</td>

.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding:0 !important;
  border:0 !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know that support for aria-label is so bad. Considering all these points, your solution is definitely better. Since I am developing a kind of style guide and just provide markup snippets, my intention was to force (or "encourage" to put it more positively ;)) the people building the site to provide some accessible content. In your case, it is possible to just omit the "visually-hidden" part without any visual difference. But of course this doesn't outweigh the drawbacks of my approach.

Comment: It's not that `aria-label` support is bad, but wrapping it in a table, and relying on everyone having current kit is sometimes tricky without knowing the audience. I encourage you to look at this support table: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/ "Reliability when used correctly (65% average)"

Comment: @josi, I have just edited the answer to include links to the support information. Sorry I left it out in original answer.

Comment: Surprising that Google sites make extensive use of aria tags. Your linked page shows continual improvement in support year to year.

Answer (score 4):

> Do you know any other drawbacks apart from that?

**On using `aria-label` attribute as a selector for styling, there's technically no problem.**

- Concerning this use of `aria-label`

It's itself not sufficient enough to be a valid alternative text for all kind of accessibility concerns.

Very few people use a screen-reader. If `aria-label` can be an help for them (depending on screen reader support, see @aardrian answer), it's of no use for a large part of the population.

A special UTF-8 code representing a checkmark is nothing else visually than an image, and users may expect, for instance, to have a tooltip. For that matter, the `title` attribute is recommended, used conjointly with `aria-label` for better browser and screen reader support.

Someone using a screen magnifier or with a a cognitive disorder, may then be able to access the alternative text of the checkmark without having to scroll to the table heading of the column.

The problem will still be important for someone with motor disabilities because having to scroll to see the heading or using the mouse to see what this checkmark means is still very difficult.

**TLDR: ARIA does not give universal accessibility for all kind of disabilities**

Comment: Your point about the checkmark character is correct. To that end, since I prefer avoiding `title` whenever possible (owing to issues I have experienced in accessible name calculation) I sometimes follow this technique: http://tink.uk/accessible-emoji/ Which I also tweaked to be keyboard accessible: http://adrianroselli.com/2016/12/accessible-emoji-tweaked.html (not a criticism of your answer, just thought you might find these posts useful)