# How to apply CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Good Day !

Can any one guide me how can I define CSS class for following blocks ? How can I select them ?

**#aria-controls="block-1599835157263** ?

```
<button class="Heading u-h1 TabList__Item " data-action="toggle-tab" aria-controls="block-1599835157263" aria-selected="false" role="tab">Sets</button>

<button class="Heading u-h1 TabList__Item " data-action="toggle-tab" aria-controls="block-1599835191363" aria-selected="false" role="tab">Skirts</button>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why you can select via class?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049551/best-practice-to-use-aria-label-as-a-selector-for-styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049551/best-practice-to-use-aria-label-as-a-selector-for-styling)

Comment: Actually there are 8 TabList__Item and I need to apply media query at 3